# Send GET Request

Tags: php, android, get

I know that there are lots of threads like this, I searched like crazy and read most of them, but can't find an answer that really helps me and works.

What I want to do is very simple, I just want to send 2 values using GET and save them in MySql.

I already have the PHP file created and is working (I tested it manually in chrome), and I have this code in Android Studio:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://myWebsite.com/connection.php");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("value1","blabla");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("value2","blabla");

    } catch(Exception e){
    Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
    }
```

I don't know what else to try, something like this should be very simple, but I can't just find a solution.

Thanks!!

Edit: 
I also tried:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://myWebsite.com/connection.php?value1=blabla&value2=blubla");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    } catch(Exception e){
    Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
    }
```

Edit 2: 
Added this to my code:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://mySite.tk/connection.php?value1=blabla&value2=blubla");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                Log.d("Progress","Sending..");
                urlConnection.connect();
                Log.d("Progress","Sent!");

            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Message",e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now Im calling " new MyTask().execute()" when clicking a button, but is not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily send GET Requests with the Google's library called Volley, it's been designed for request on Android

I recommand you to consider using Volley for your futur requests, here is an example of a GET request :

```
final String url = "http://yourScript.com/scipt.php";

// prepare the Request
JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {   
                        // display response     
            Log.d("Response", response.toString());
        }
    }, 
    new Response.ErrorListener() 
    {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            
            Log.d("Error.Response", response);
       }
    }
){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("parameter1", param1);
            map.put("parameter2", param2); 

            return map;
        }
    };

// add it to the RequestQueue   
queue.add(getRequest);
```

Comment: This helped, I added the code and modified to what I need just had to download the volley.jar and insert it in the libs folder of my project. Awesome! Thank you!!
The only thing that im not sure (But is working) is that I'm sending the get Request here final String url = "http://yourScript.com/scipt.php?value=vala&value2=vala2";
Is that the way that it works? Or should I send the request in the HashMap?

Comment: Actually I dont know because I usually use Post requests ! Try the both ways with tests in your php script ( `if(isset($_GET['parameter1']))` )

Comment: Oh ok, yes, I think that the HashMap is only being used for post request, that is actually more secure. Once again, thank you!

Comment: Ok, I did't knew it ! You're welcome, I'm glad I could help you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Get values aren't sent as properties.  They're sent as part of the URL.  http://example.com/myurl?variable1=value1&variable2=value2

Comment: You are right, also tried that before changing to "setRequestProperty".

Comment: Well you did do urlConnection .connect and actually read in the result, right?  I presumed you were just having problems sending the variables.  The code above creates the object, it doesn't actually hit your webserver yet.

Comment: I just added urlConnection.connect(); above the last line in Try{}. Now Im getting this error: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: You can't network on the main thread.  You have to do it on another thread or an async task.  But you're now trying to reach your webserver, so you're on the right path-  before you weren't actually sending the request.

Comment: Great! thank you! Just found a something here in StackOverflow about this, adding this is supposed to help, is that correct?
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: Don't do that.  Do it the right way with an AsyncTask.  Adding a strict mode exception doesn't work on all devices, and its a way of allowing you to have sloppy code that won't perform well.  It'll come back to bite you in the ass.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108856/discussion-between-laurenzanoster-and-gabe-sechan).

Comment: Added some extra information to the Topic, now im using AsyncTask as you suggested